# Primer for old oil-based paint

Tags: painting

I'm confused and hope you can help.  I thought ANY primer - I just bought five gallons of Kilz latex primer - could be used over old oil-based paint and then a new coat of latex paint applied successfully.  Today, per Home Depot recommendation I bought a gallon of the oil-based Kilz for a couple of small jobs.  I thought I'd read that latex primer over oil-based paint is just fine.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can overcoat over any old paint if these things are true:

- The paint is **fully** cured (which can take up to a year or two for single-can paints which rely on air or atmospheric moisture to cure.)   Curing is not the same as drying.  Curing is the paint molecules "holding hands", polymerizing into much longer molecules.
- You scuff-sand the old paint so the surface has microscopic ridges and valleys ("tooth"), a Scotchbrite pad will suffice, this will remove the gloss from the paint.  Be careful not to blow through corners and ridges.
- You clean the surface thoroughly to remove grease, oil, dirt and the like.  Especially important in kitchens!

Classically one might use TSP (Tri-Sodium Phospate) to attempt to both clean greases and etch the surface.

Where does primer enter the picture?

- You want a primer over *bare material*.  Original oil Kilz is high-performing over wood.  It's not the very best; that's a marine 2-part epoxy primer.  Over aluminum or steel you'd want a zinc chromate primer (the classic green color of unpainted aircraft), over steel I just tend to go Rustoleum.
- When you have dissimilar surfaces or colors, and you want to normalize them so they don't "print through".
- If your topcoat doesn't want to stick to the surface as-is, this is called a *barrier coat*.

If you don't have any of those situations, a primer may not be needed.

I am no fan of the Kilz latex primer; I feel the oil-based product is far more suitable for wood.  Perhaps the Kilz latex makes sense over drywall; you certainly do need a primer for that.